# MySQL query results not updating in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I created a simple Python script which queries every 0.5 seconds my Database and prints the results every time. I'm using Schedule to run the script every 0.5 seconds, here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
import json, schedule, time

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="mydb"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def testing():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT x FROM mydb")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult)

schedule.every(0.5).seconds.do(testing)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I noticed that if i edit something on that DB table while the script is running, the script will keep printing data from my **without** that edit, to actually see my edits being reflected on the query, i will have to restart the script. Instead, if i edit something on the database while the script is running, i want to see the script printing the current state of the database, not the old one.Can anyone tell me what is happening here and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you move `mycursor = mydb.cursor()` to `testing()`?

Comment: Any chance you're editing the base with autocommit set to 0? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: @Tomasito665 i tried it, same input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line `mydb.commit()` inside the `testing()` function worked. Now the query is being updated successfully.